# change the kernel version OS

Tags: linux, kernel, security, source

It is possible to modify the linux kernel,
I have tried to search but I can't find anything related in the source code

I want to modify this line **GNU/Linux**
I have noticed that there are kernels with different names / **GNU/Hurd,  GNU/Kwindos ,GNU/FreeBSD**

I would like to know if it is possible to change from the kernel source code
**GNU/CUSTOM** o **GNU/myNAME**

Comment: It sounds like you want to compile a  custom kernel. Several guides exist such as [this](https://tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/kernel-custom.html) or google for compiling a Linux kernel.

Comment: Also, the other kernels you mentioned have nothing to do with Linux.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know if it is possible to change from the kernel source code GNU/CUSTOM o GNU/myNAME

You're confusing things.

The Linux kernel is called "Linux". Not "GNU/Linux".
Only the GNU coreutils `uname` command line tool, when asked for an operating system description using `uname -o` (or `-a`), prints that.

It does that because it is a GNU program and gnulib has decided for its own that this is the right thing to print on any host operating system that is Linux¹.

So, you can replace that, no big deal. Just change the [configure script of gnulib](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/m4/host-os.m4#L52) to hardcode a different value. That will make the `uname` program call your system differently. (Nothing else cares.)

So, your kernel is **not** called "GNU/Linux". It's "Linux".

You can also replace what the Linux kernel itself calls itself when asked for it (using the `uname` system call, which is not the same as the command line `uname` tool of the same name). But that comes at a high price: Programs used that name to figure out whether they are on Linux, FreeBSD, Windows or MS-DOS 3.2. If you change that, a lot of things might stop working, building software might fail because the configure scripts are not making any sense anymore, and so on.

Also, being GPL, you need to deliver the full source code of your kernel to whoever you ship the binary kernel to. So, calling your modified Linux kernel "JonathannOS" will make your life harder, and everyone else will revert your change, because it's just annoying to work with.

---

¹ Calling every Linux system a "GNU/Linux" system is a lie, by the way.
There's probably more devices in 2022 that run a Linux kernel without any GNU software than there are devices running a Linux kernel with GNU userland. See: Over three billion (!) Android phones, busybox/musl/newlib/bsdlib-based consumer routers, a lot of TVs, smart cameras, cellular modems, almost all new automotive infotainment systems that legally cannot use GPL software… None of these contain any GNU code. Not even the compiler is necessarily GNU. The command will regardless claim that you're using a "GNU/Linux" system. To be fair, though, if you're using the `uname` command, chances are you're not one of them.

Comment: Coreutils `uname` on my Android phone says “Android”, not “GNU/Linux” ;-).

Comment: hah! That's interesting, [considering the code](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/m4/host-os.m4#L52)

Comment: investigated some more, the busybox built-in `uname` gives plain `Linux` when asked for `-o`; not something like `GNU/Linux`, or `busy/Linux` or whatever one would have come up with :D At least when built against musl instead of glibc

Comment: In my case [the “Android” string is hard-coded in the build](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/blob/master/packages/coreutils/build.sh#L20), so it’s not related to anything done in gnulib itself (and thus doesn’t mean all that much).

Comment: Heh, funny. Asked a friend, NetBSD's `uname` doesn't even have a `-o`, but `uname -mnrpsv` will just tell you "NetBSD".